# My visual studio can't connect to tfs server with Valid IP

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have installed a TFS server in my local machine as you  can see :
[image]

every thing works fine in my local machine and my visual can connect to TFS as you  can see :

[image]

I said to my network administrator to set a valid IP for my local system to access to my TFS outside of company .
He set the IP but when i try to connect to that i get this error :

[image]

Comment: Do you have a try to connect the TFS within company network with the IP? Can you get any response if you ping your TFS with the IP outside of company? Firstly, please make sure the network is OK. Then you can try to troubleshoot according to this article :https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/error/tf31002-unable-connect-tfs

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is on the bottom of the error dialog and it says:

> The remove server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

You should double-check that you are logged on under user account that has permissions to access TFS. You might want to try Windows Credential Manager to store your domain credentials in case you log on using local Windows account when outside of company.